# Seeking Comp (Comparison) Titles for my Work-In-Progress

Tags: fantasy, science-fiction, book-rec

Seeking comp titles for my WIP. Can you recommend books that meet one or more of these criteria?

- Soft sci-fi
- Space setting with fantasy feel
- Speculative fiction about species that has advanced technology but doesn't place much value on it (similar to the way we value indoor lighting)

I'm looking for something like James Cameron's Avatar movie: science fiction genre that comes across more like fantasy.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "[Sword and planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_and_planet)" fantasy subgenre?

Comment: Moreau, I'm sure many writers will disagree with me, but unless an agent has specifically asked for comps (if that's why you're asking) I wouldn't waste time seeking one out. If your work compares to something well-known (that you love) in the marketplace, fantastic, use it. But if you have to seek it out, it's probably too obscure. There's a good chance the agent won't have read it, rendering it meaningless and wasting precious words in your query. And if they hated it, you could ruin your chances right there. It's a risky business and, personally, I wouldn't recommend doing it. cont...

Comment: ... I'd argue that you don't need it. Keep your query short and use your words like precious diamonds. You're much better off focussing all your energy into a one para pitch that summarises your own story perfectly while making it sound irresistible and unputdownable. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to find comparative titles that **augment** your query, not repeat it. A novel has a plot, but also characters, tense, style, stakes, tension, forces-at-play, setting, age limit, and so on. Some of these will be indicated in your query. Some will not. If your query describes your plot, for example, you may wish to comp a book that is similar in another way.

Also, you can comp to a movie according to agents on twitter, or to an author or to a character.

Example: *"My book may be thought of as 'Atticus Finch on the International Space Station'"* <- evokes a bizarre science fiction and crazy feel without either of those 'comps' being a book *per se,* or in science fiction.

Agents also seem to ask for recent comps, to ensure you 'know the market.' This is not as high of a hurdle as it initially sounds. Have you visited your local library? Ours has a new book shelf with titles acquired from the last six months (published in the last year or so.) There are about thirty titles under science fiction on that shelf in our library.

It took a scant forty five minutes for me to read the blurb on each of these thirty new science fiction titles, set aside the ones that could possibly fit my WIP in some way, any way, and check those out to look through at home. Of those six, three work as comps.

My best **answer** is to look through new books at your local library and pull any that have any comparative value at all to your WIP. Broaden your view of what a comp can accomplish, and tailor your comps to the agents you query.